# sql pulling from sub query

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is it possible to pull 2 results from a sub query in a sql statement?

I have:

```
"SELECT 
  (SELECT bid FROM auction_bids WHERE itemID=a.id ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT 1) as topbid,
     a.* FROM auction_items a ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 15"
```

The part where it returns the `topbid`, i'd also like it to pull not only `bid` (as topbid) but also `date` (as topdate) as well. How can I do that? Do I need another sub query or can it pull both in one?

Comment: instead go for cross join ,,it is much easy comparing with the above functionality SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4)
                 ON (t2.a=t1.a AND t3.b=t1.b AND t4.c=t1.c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependent subquery (depending on some values outside, like a.id in your case) is not a very efficient way to find maximum values in subsets.

Instead use a subquery with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT b.topbid, b.topdate, a.* 
FROM auction_items a
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT itemID, MAX(bid) as topbid, MAX(date) as topdate 
  FROM auction_bids
  GROUP BY itemID ) b
ON a.id = b.itemID
ORDER BY a.date DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: aegh, Im trying to order them by `b.topdate` and `a.date` (when item was added) but it's not ordering them correct: `"SELECT b.topbid, b.topdate, a.* FROM auction_items a LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemID, MAX(bid) as topbid, MAX(date) as topdate FROM auction_bids GROUP BY itemID ) b ON a.id = b.itemID ORDER BY b.topdate DESC, a.date DESC LIMIT 20"`